# A difficulty in understanding the proof of 7.2.3 Petrovic.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The question and its answer is given below:

Suppose that  {a_n} is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers. Prove that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges iff $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^n  a_{2^n}$ converges.

**The answer is:**

[image]
[image]

But I could not understand why the seventh line in the answer implies the eighth one  ($t_{n} \leq a_0 + 2s_{2^n}$).....could anyone explain this for me? I seem to have a difficulty in comparing the elements of $s_{2^n}$ with those in the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_j\leq a_k$ for $j\geq k$, we have that 
$$a_2+2a_4+ \dots+2^{n-1}a_{2^n}=
a_2+(a_4+a_4)+ \dots+(a_{2^{n-1}+1}+\dots+a_{2^n})
\\\leq a_2+(a_3+a_4)+ \dots+(a_{2^{n-1}+1}+\dots+a_{2^n})=s_{2^n}-a_1-a_0\leq s_{2^n}.$$

Comment: Does $s_{2^n}$ contain $a_{0}$? I do not think so

Comment: Why not? According to your definition $s_{2^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n}a_k$.

Comment: is not it $a_{2^k}$ not $a_{k}$? or this is my mistake?

Comment: It is  $a_k$. Now I understand why you were confused about that inequality. In  $s_m$ $m$ is the **final index** in the sum.

Comment: I have another question please in the sixth line of the solution  equality $t_{n} = a_{0} + ......$ from where $a_{0}$ came, should not it be $a_{1}$ instead?

Comment: Also, for the other direction why we start to compute $S_{2^n -1}$ why this subscript ${2^n -1}$ especially?

Comment: $a_0$ comes from $S_{2^n -1}$. We compute $s_{2^n -1}$ (or $s_{2^n}$ because we already found a lower bound in terms of $t_n$.

Comment: what is the relation with $S_{2^n -1}$?  in the proof of the first direction, in the sixth line we are speaking about $t_{n}$ only.

Comment: I am saying that there is a typo in the proof of the first part

Comment: What typo? Anyway this is the Cauchy condensation test. See for example an alternative proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073280/what-is-the-first-term-in-this-partial-sum-t-n-sum-k-0n-2k-a-2k  this clarifies the typo I am speaking about

Comment: Ok. You are right. It should be $t_n\leq a_1+2s_{2^n}$ in the first part and $s_{2^n-1}\leq a_0+t_{n-1}$ in the second part.

Comment: thank you for your patience