# What is the first term in this partial sum $t_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k a_{2^k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the first term in this partial sum $t_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k a_{2^k}$?

I found it to be $a_{1}$(by substituting $ k=0 $ and knowing that 2^0 =1 ) but the book always says that it is $a_{0}$, could anyone remove this discrepancy for me please?

Comment: From the information given in the question, it would seem that you are correct.

Comment: @Zachary here is the whole information  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071844/a-difficulty-in-understanding-the-proof-of-7-2-3-petrovic?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. We have $t_n=a_1+2a_2+4a_4+....+2^na_{2^n}$, hence the first term in $t_n$ is $a_1$.